# EmptyThrowable: Failed to create the SD card

Tags: android, unix

LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 
Release:    7.0.1406
Codename:   Core
--- [image]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set a x86_64 OS image for your emulator which AFAIK only works (and optimized) for Intel processor with virtualization support. Your machine has AMD processor within so, using OS images of such kind is a no go for you. Try to use ARM images instead.

PS. Try to be a tad more detailed in your question when you seek help/suggestion in stackoverflow.